# Correct "Edge Effect" on Farm Field Soil Data Rasters or After converting to Vector Layer

Tags: qgis, raster

I am using satellite imagery to determine like soil zones using a Jenks Analysis. I have my method figured out but some fields have a significant "Edge Influence" from trees overhanging into the field, road, brush or grass. My field boundaries are set to the edge of the plow. Is there a good way to filter out the edge anomalies and back fill with interpolated data? I’ve tried making the pixels "null data" and filling nulls with bilinear interpolation but pixel by pixel is tedious and ends up with not so great results. I am using QGIS then loading the results into SMS Ag Leader.

[image]

[image: Green Edge Influence]